# QuickFix/n Web Interface Message Traffic Viewer

Tags: quickfixn

We are using QuickFix/n source code to implement FIX Engine in .Net Core. QuickFix/n has a Web Interface to manage Sessions. Is there a way to view all the incoming and outgoing messages for the Sessions?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing all the raw messages to a file for each session and displaying on web interface.